# Linking to a custom framework using cmake - correct location at build, wrong location at runtime

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, frameworks

So, I have a custom built framework, which is located at:

```
/usr/local/Frameworks/QGLViewer.framework
```

I then have these lines in my CMakeLists.txt to use it:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH "/usr/local/Frameworks")
find_library(QGLViewer_LIBRARY QGLViewer)
if(NOT QGLViewer_LIBRARY)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "QGLViewer library not found")
endif()

...

add_executable(OpenGLTest ${MY_SOURCES} ${MY_HEADERS} ${MY_UI_HDRS} ${MY_MOC_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(OpenGLTest
    ${OpenGL_LIBS} 
    ${QT_LIBRARIES} 
    ${QGLViewer_LIBRARY}
    )
```

When I build this, it builds fine - it finds the framework at `/usr/local/Frameworks/QGLViewer.framework`.  However, when linking at runtime, it fails - tries to find the framework at `/Library/Frameworks/QGLViewer.framework`, which doesn't exist.

If I do:

```
otool -l OpenGLTest
```

then I see this line:

```
Load command 19
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /Library/Frameworks/QGLViewer.framework/Versions/A/QGLViewer (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 16:00:02 1969
      current version 0.0.0
compatibility version 0.0.0
```

...which I think means that the incorrect location has somehow gotten baked into the build at runtime.

Possibly related - at some point, I had the library located at `/Library/Frameworks/QGLViewer.framework`, and built my executable using it at that location.  I could go back to that layout, and it works, but wanted to move the framework to `/usr/local/Frameworks`, since that makes more sense to me for "my frameworks", and it's where all the (brew-built) Qt frameworks live.  I thought maybe some dyld caching was the culprit, but I tried running `update_dyld_shared_cache -force`, and it didn't help...

Comment: You can add path to framework libs to LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable